# Use template in the middle of a sentence

Tags: org-mode

`tempo-define-template` allows defining a custom template, and one can use it with `<key` + TAB; however, this works only in the beginning of the line, it there a way to do that in middle of a sentence?

Comment: do you want the template inserted in the middle of the sentence, or you want it to start at the beginning of the next line?

Comment: in the middle of the sentence, to avoid retype long words/sentences

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this wold look like. Can you show me? The only use case I could think of was to wrap the current line in the template, but your comment says in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right tool to use in this case is `yasnippet`: https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/